# ORA-12154 Error while connecting grid view in ASP.net to oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g, ora-12154

Details:

- username is scott
- password is tiger
- Server name - I gave prashanth-PC, which I found in tnsnames.ora - at this point I get

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifer specified

When I connect using code, it is working. In code I will leave data source blank. But when I connect using the grid view tool. It is asking server name. I don't know which server name should I specify. For reference I have posted the contents of my "tnsnames.ora" file. Please check it. Am using Oracle 10g.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = prashanth-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
)


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: I don't know what is the "grid view tool", but did you try "XE" as server name ?

Comment: Yes i tried "XE" also..But getting same error..Grid view is a control in visual studio toolbox..

Comment: what do you get when you do (from cmd) "tnsping XE" ?

Comment: Is your TNS_ADMIN environment variable set to point to the directory of the tnsnames.ora file ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the ".Net Framework Data provider for oracle" as your provider.
In this case the server name should contain the "alias" from your tnsnames.ora - in your case "XE".
The error you get may be caused because it can't find the tnsnames.ora file.
Make sure you set the "TNS_ADMIN" environment variabl to point to the path of the directory containing the tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 0):

Server name expects the Oracle service name, not your machine host name. Try entering XE at the server name. If this fails:

- Check if you have multiple `tnsnames.ora` file
- If so, ensure all the `tnsnames.ora` files are in sync **or** find out which tnsnames.ora 
  is in use - This can be done by checking your path variable & finding out which path has the first mention of tnsnames.ora
- Also ensure that the tns listener service is up & running from the Windows Services list

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue just now. What I was trying to do was to provide share to the TNS files folder, located under **"Admin"** folder of the oracle client installation location, with developer folks to ensure that the sanity of TNSentries on the server.

What I noticed was that when I applied the share over the **"Admin"** folder, the  **"(LocalHostName)\Authenticated Users"** was removed from the security context of the **"Admin"** folder.

Once I added **"Authenticated Users"** back to the security context of the folder with default rights, the error was gone.

OS version: **Win 2012 DC Edition**

Oracle client Client: **Oracle client 11.2.0**